# What does RU (UR) label on DC power relays mean?

Tags: relay, dc

I'm trying to figure out what does *RU* or maybe *UR* label mean on the body of many many relays. It's labeled almost on all (I've seen so far) DC relays which make me very curious :). Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a UL label. From [UL wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UL_(safety_organization)):

> The "Recognized Component Mark" is a type of quality mark issued by Underwriters Laboratories. It is placed on components which are intended to be part of a UL listed product, but which cannot bear the full UL logo themselves.[6] The general public does not ordinarily come across it, as it is borne on components which make up finished products.
>   [image]

Answer (score 8):

RU is an Underwriter's Laboratories mark for certified products that are intended to be used inside of other devices.

[Reference:  The UL site.](http://ul.com/marks/ul-listing-and-classification-marks/appearance-and-significance/marks-for-north-america/)

Answer (score 7):

It is the **Recognized Component Mark**  UL

> As a basis for approval, code authorities look for UL Listing Marks to
>   verify that products have been investigated for installation in the
>   field in accordance with model codes. During inspections of electrical
>   installations, code authorities may see a variety of certification
>   marks, including the UL Listing Mark and UL Recognized Component Mark.
>   To properly approve the installation, it is important for code
>   authorities to understand the meaning of each of these marks as well
>   as the important differences between them. The UL Listing Mark is the
>   most common certification mark seen and accepted by code authorities.

http://ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ul_RecognizedComponentMarks.pdf

Answer (score 6):

UL listings are for **products**. ЯU is for **components** and it means the component is pre-approved.

Say you design a DVR or smart-switch.  The DVR needs a UL listing to be sold at retail.  The smart switch needs a UL listing to be installed in mains wiring (NEC 110.2).  You send the unit into UL, and they go through the unit with a fine-tooth comb.

For instance there's a relay in there, they'll pop it off the PCB and do their tests - hi-pot, current, throw cycles, physical teardown, toxic-smoke test (if burned), etc. This costs you money.

**However, when they see the ЯU mark on the relay, they don't test it. It's already tested and approved**. When your PCB is covered with ЯU components, listing is cheaper, faster, and there's less uncertainty.

Note that you can get a UL product listing from ETL, CSA, BSI, TUV, or any other Nationally Recognized Testing Lab. But they'll just follow the same rules as UL.  A few Chinese junkmakers in the smart-switch space are trying to "go legit", and I notice they prefer ETL.